# How do you play a PC DVD game on Mac?

Tags: pc, civilization-5, macos

I have got Civilization V Gold edition as a PC DVD ROM. I was wondering how I could play this on Mac? Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Civilization V requires you to use Steam to play, so your physical copy should have come with a serial/game key.

Install [Steam and create an account](https://store.steampowered.com) if you haven't yet, then [redeem the key](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5414-tfbn-1352) once you logged in. From there you can just download the game.